# Missing record of some successful embedded signing signatures in our db, only see 'session_timeout' in logs

Tags: docusignapi

Our embedded signing workflow works *most* of the time (I'd estimate over 95%) for the majority of our users going through our application. However, about once or twice a week we discover an individual that has successfully signed the document via DocuSign embedded signing, but our own database has no record of the signature, so we have to manually create a record in our database of the missing signature to update our application. I'm trying to debug why this happens, but I'm running out of ideas.

We rely on the `returnUrl` attribute of the [**CreateRecipientView** endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/#schema__recipientviewrequest_returnurl) to redirect the user back to our server, and that is when we do two very basic things that work *most* of the time:

1. We record the DocuSign event to our logs table, regardless of what is returned.
2. IF the event received is `signing_complete`, then we save the signature to our database.

Even if there is an error on our server processing the response and saving the signature details, our server should have already logged the raw response so we can inspect it. Given this, even if there was an error on our end, I would at least expect to see a "signing_complete" event in our logs for someone who has signed. When this particular situation occurs, the only DocuSign responses I see in our logs are `viewing_complete` and a few `session_timeout`.

Is it even possible that the user could successfully sign AND be sent back to us with a `session_timeout` event? Or can I be confident that a successful signature will *always* result in a redirect with a `signing_complete` event?

Anything else I should check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We rely on the returnUrl attribute of the CreateRecipientView endpoint
> to redirect the user back to our server, and that is when we do two
> very basic things that work most of the time:

You should not rely on this. It's not going to work 100% of the time. This is because relying on the client is tricky. In some situations your end-users session may not be reliable, internet loss, they hit back, they closed browser by mistake etc. There are countless of ways to account for the 5% of the "lost" envelopes.

Instead use a [Connect webhook](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/). This approach will work 100% of the time and will be much more reliable.

All you had to do is set up the webhook (once) and set up an endpoint, other than the one you had, to process any envelope that is complete. It's not much different than what you're doing now, but it will be more reliable.

Webhooks even have retry mechanism, so if DocuSign can't reach your server for any reason, DocuSign will try again later.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I had originally set this up with a webhook but I had to revert to using the return URL. I think my problem was that the webhook wasn't running and completing before the returnURL redirection completed. (I thought there was a delay of a few minutes, which wouldn't work for me, but I can't confirm this anywhere.) Are you aware of any delays with webhooks like this?

Comment: yes, there could be a delay. If you want both speedy and 100% reliable solution you should use both. The webhook as a backup to catch these 5% that the client misses.

Comment: I hadn't considered both. I'll definitely do this. Thanks!

Do you know if the webhook delay is documented anywhere? I thought I previously saw mention of it saying it could take a few minutes before, but now I can't find it anywhere in the docs. (I'm mostly just wondering if it always runs in a set time, or if it can vary depending on traffic and other factors.)

Comment: It's not something we can document, because it changes based on server load, volumes of envelopes, the size of the documents etc. I think we have some number regarding worse case scenario, let me see if I can find it.

Answer (score 1):

I second Inbar's comment. Webhooks are the right pattern for this issue. If you can't put a server on the internet to receive the webhooks from DocuSign, you can have the webhooks go to an IaaS system such as AWS or Azure.

Then your app (behind your firewall) can poll the IaaS system.

Here's an [article where I outline how to do this](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhook-listeners-part-4).

Plus I see that [webhook.site](https://webhook.site) enables you to have the webhook notifications sent to them, and your app can then poll them via their [Get API action](https://docs.webhook.site/api/tokens.html#get-requests)